# Python/Flask - Problem with RPi.GPIO event detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, flask, raspberry-pi3

I am currently working on the alarm system using Python(Flask) and Raspberry.

I have a front page with only one button: "ARM" that redirects to "/ARM" and a page "/DISARM":

```
@app.route('/ARM')
def ARM():
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(sensor)      

    # Blue LED on
    GPIO.output(blue,1)                                  

    # detection based on motion sensor
    GPIO.add_event_detect(sensor, GPIO.RISING, callback=alert)  

    # The template with "DISARM" button
    return render_template('home_disarm.html') 


@app.route('/DISARM')
def DISARM():
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(sensor)

    # blue LED off / red LED off / buzzer off
    GPIO.output(blue,0)
    GPIO.output(red,0)
    GPIO.output(buzz,0)

    # the template with "ARM" button
    return render_template('home.html')
```

When the motion sensor detects movement, callback function "alert" is executed:

```
def alert(sensor):
        GPIO.remove_event_detect(sensor)

        # Blue LED off / Red LED on / Buzzer on
        GPIO.output(blue,0)
        GPIO.output(red,1)
        GPIO.output(buzz,1)

        # wait 20s for automatic disarming
        sleep(20)
        GPIO.output(blue,1)
        GPIO.output(red,0)
        GPIO.output(buzz,0)

        # arm again
        GPIO.add_event_detect(sensor, GPIO.RISING, callback=int)
```

When the system is armed (but not triggered) it can be disarmed, but the problem is in disactivating the system after the detection (20s period). When I try disarming it in that period, it works for awhile, but after 20s the server is down. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could the server be timed out?

Comment: You only show the code for the callback `albert`, but you didn't show the callback which `int` which could caused the problem. Also what the meaning of 'server is down'? any server log that provide the clue?